# Canvas/Layers are stacking when I restart KineticJS game. Causing performance issues.

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I made a game using KineticJS and added a standard html button that allows the user to restart the game. I basically wrapped all of the game code in a function, then attached the function to the button. It works but each time the game reloads it becomes significantly slower. I think it's because the canvas and layers are being regenerated each time and being stacked on top of each other.

I tried adding destroy() to the click handler but it just froze the page. I think it might be some kind of scoping issue having to do with creating and deleting a canvas at the same time.

If anybody could take a look at my jsfiddle and see if they can figure out a way to let the user restart the game without having it effect performance I would really appreciate the input.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/fwS2d/

The specific jQuery call is at the end of the code:

```
 $('#restart').on('click' , function(){
restart();
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not work for me. Anyway, I would solve this by keeping track of the positions of all elements in your game and reset them to their initial value. No need to create all elements and everything around.

Comment: Yes, your fiddle is missing necessary linked files :-(

Answer (score 0):

You defined a single restart function, in which you always use vars to store the objects created, which is clean.  I bet that you relied on those closures to have the garbage collector wipe out things when they're no longer in use.
Yet there's already one thing you should wonder about, even before thinking of restarting the game : when restart() is called the first time, all the init process is done, then the function returns : why won't every object get recollected at that point ?
It's because there are still 3 types of links in between those objects and the global object :
- DOM content.  (contentStage is an object linked to 'content' div.)
- event handlers. (mouse).
- timers.  (setInterval).

When you call restart again, you'll pile new content/handlers/timers and the older ones won't get reclaimed : for instance, you'll have more and function called by the setIntervals -hence the slowdown-.

==> you need to add a clear() function that will clear the DOM, remove mouse handlers, and clear all Intervals.
Only after clearing you can safely call restart() to have a brand new game.
Watch out not to keep any reference to any object.